# Regex to match only numbers in currency

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm trying to get a VB regex to match only the numbers in a currency sequence without additional substitution lines if possible. It needs to look for a number with + on end $ at the start and return what's in the middle, minus any commas.

Accordingly

```
 $10,000+ match returns 10000

$20,000+ match returns 20000

$30,000+ match returns 30000

$1,000,000+ match returns 1000000

$10,000 (anything without the trailing +) should *not* match
```

I can easily get the match to the value but I can't figure out how to get rid, of the trailing + or the prefix and commas inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is `\$(\d+(,?\d+)*)\+`. Group 1 is what you are looking for 
Check [here](https://regex101.com/r/HQEMuC/2)

After retrieving results you should remove commas from it